# Is It good to subscribe to an observable within another subscription handler?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm using Angular2 and I have a question about what is the best way to do if I have many observables.
Can I put subscriptions inside each other or put each one in a different method and put the results in class properties?

Example :

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.params**.subscribe**(params => {
   if (params['id']) {
    this.load = true;
     this.batchService.getPagesOfCurrentObject(params['id'], "10", "0")
       **.subscribe**(result => {
         this.stream = result;
         if (this.stream.length > 0) {
           this.stream.forEach(page => { this.batchService.getPageStreamById
           (page.pageId)**.subscribe**(pageStream => {
              let base64 = btoa(new Uint8Array(pageStream.data)
                 .reduce((data, byte) 
                    => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), ''));
               this.pages.push(base64 );

             })

             return;
           });
         }

     },
       error => this.errorService.setError(<any>error),
       () => this.load = false
       );
   }
 });

 try {
   this.customer = this.sharedService.processSelect.subscription.customer;
 } catch (err) {
   return;
 }
}
```

Comment: Most of the time there is a cleaner way to do everything, this could easily the case. But this is not angular related, just rxjs and programming style in general

Comment: You don't have observables inside each other, you have subscriptions inside each other. As far as I know, it's good, you just wait for your data to come before making another call.

Comment: Can you please describe in English what your code is trying to do? Subscriptions within subscriptions are almost always an anti-pattern, and in many cases would better be handled with `switchMap` or `flatMap` or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Having multiple observables is totally fine, this is what reactive programming is about :)

But here your problem is having too much `subscribe`. Keep in mind that `subscribe` is a way to create side effect. To have an easy to read code, you should try to use the least possible `subscribe`.

Your use case is the perfect use case for the `mergeMap` operator, that allows you to flatten nested observables.

Here what your code would look like

```
const response$ = this.route.params
  .mergeMap(params => {
    return this.batchService.getPagesOfCurrentObject(params['id'])
  })
  .mergeMap(stream => {
    return Rx.Observable.merge(stream.map(page => this.batchService.getPageStreamById(page.pageId))
  })
  .map(pageStream => /* do your stuff with pageStream, base64 ... */)

response$.subscribe(pageStreamData => pages.push(pageStreamData))
```

See how there is a single subscription that triggers the side-effect that will modify your app's state

Note that I voluntarily simplified the code (removed error handling and checks) for you to get the idea of how to do that.

I hope it will help you thinking in reactive programming :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have an error : Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.  (method) BatchService.getPagesOfCurrentObject(batchID: string, limit: string, offset: string): Observable<any[]>

Comment: You need to re-add the extra parameters I have removed from my answer `getPagesOfCurrentObject(params['id'], "10", "0")` I think

Comment: does that help?

Comment: No yet now because this.pages.length is always equal to 0: I just add : .map(pageStream => { pageStream.subscribe(stream => { let base64 = btoa(new Uint8Array(stream.data).reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')); return base64; }); })

Comment: Yeah that's because you are subscribing inside a `map` thus not returning anything from your stream. You should use the `mergeMap` as I showed in my answer to pass on data to the next observer

Comment: Sorry I don't reach to know how to do that. I tried to do a return of pageStream.mergeMap but it returns observables and not a datas

Comment: if you `console.log` what is inside `pageStream` in this function, do you get what you expect?

Comment: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MergeMapOperator}
operator
:
MergeMapOperator
source
:
Observable
_isScalar
:
false
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Oh so that's an observable, you need to `mergeMap` the previous step

Comment: I am sorry, it's kind of hard to debug from here considering I cannot execute the code :/